# Importing Large Data Set into Core-Data (Solution with Multiple Stores)

Tags: ios, json, core-data, import

I know this topic has been discussed, but I'm looking for a specific solution which has been discussed anywhere i.e. using multiple stores instead of one -- one for default data, and other for user entered data.

In my application, I want to preload large amount of data i.e. 20 MB json file, for Entity X (only). The model also contains Entity Y and Entity Z as well. The solution that I think best suits my needs is as follows:

> Use two sqlite databases. One database for Entity X only, which can be replaced in future versions of the application... without affect the data of Entity Y and Entity Z (effortlessly).

- How can I implement such a solution?
- Is it practical?
- Will I have to make two models?
- How will I setup core data managed object context in such a scenario?

**Details (just in-case):**

I have two options (as suggested):

1. Bundle json file with the application and load on first launch of the application
2. Generate a sqlite database, and ship application with pre-populated database

With first option, I have following concerns:

- The application startup will be slow (as it'll take sometime to parse a 20 MB file and then create corresponding records in core-data).
- Once the file has been used, there's no need for that 20 MB space, which the application is using. I don't think there's anyway to get rid of that file, of is there?

With second option, I have following concerns:

- Lets say that in Version 2.0 of my application, I want to update the default store. For example, the default sqlite database I shipped in Version 1.0 had some issues, or I want to add some more "default" records? I have more than one entities, and user may have added data to other entities. So, I can't replace the sqlite database. So, how can I go about updating the records in my database?

Comment: From your explanation, what would be the issue with using multiple entities in one persistent store vs 2 stores and multiple entities? I see no reason why you can't accomplish the same thing with just multiple entities. That way you can just simply preload all your data into the one entity and then when you are done with it just delete all the objects in that entity.

Comment: btw, to remove files, try [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:myLocalURL error:&error];

Comment: Okay, so I can preload a sqlite database for Entity X, and ship it with my application v1.0. Now, what will I do when I have to change some entries... and update the default database for Entity X in v2.0?

Comment: I can't remove files from my bundle, can I?

Comment: if your json file is a simple file in your project structure you should be able to remove it with NSFileManager (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's really better to hold 2 databases, because you mostly change more than only the one to extend functionalities.

For database migration, you can use something like this.

First use the internal versioning system of the core-data and hold your currently used version in the `NSUserDefaults` and in my example the `infoDictionary` (your connected .plist file). So you can first try the lightweight migration and then the manuel if you changes cannot be automaticaly merged.

```
NSNumber *newDbVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"DBVersion"];
NSNumber *oldDbVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DBVersion"];

NSURL *storeUrlOld;
if(!oldDbVersion)
    storeUrlOld = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"default.sqlite"]]; // default path
else
    storeUrlOld = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"db_%d.sqlite",[oldDbVersion intValue]]]];

NSURL *storeUrlNew = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"db_%d.sqlite",[newDbVersion intValue]]]];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDB" ofType:@"momd"];
if(oldDbVersion)
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"db_%d.mom", [oldDbVersion intValue]]];

NSURL *momURLOld = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSLog(@"mom-path old: %@", path);
NSLog(@"mom-url old: %@", momURLOld);

NSManagedObjectModel *oldManagedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURLOld];

// - - -

path = nil;
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"momd"];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"db_%d.mom",[newDbVersion intValue]]];

NSURL *momURLNew = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSLog(@"mom-path new: %@", path);
NSLog(@"mom-url new: %@", momURLNew);
NSManagedObjectModel *newManagedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURLNew];

// # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
// - - - - Connect with old Database - - - -
// # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

NSError *error;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinatorOld = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:oldManagedObjectModel];

// Allow inferred migration from the original version of the application.
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

if (![persistentStoreCoordinatorOld addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrlOld options:options error:&error]) 
{
    // Handle the error
    NSLog(@"Failed to add old persistent store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];

    if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) 
    {
        for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
            NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR persistentStoreCoordinator: %@", [error userInfo]);
    }
    return;
}

NSManagedObjectContext *oldManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[oldManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinatorOld];

// # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
// - - - - Connect with new Database - - - -
// # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinatorNew = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: newManagedObjectModel];

if (![persistentStoreCoordinatorNew addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrlNew options:options error:&error]) 
{
    // Handle the error
    NSLog(@"Failed to add new persistent store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];

    if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) 
    {
        for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
            NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR persistentStoreCoordinator: %@", [error userInfo]);
    }
    return;
}    

NSManagedObjectContext *newManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[newManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinatorNew];
managedObjectContext = newManagedObjectContext;

// # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
// - - - Transfere data from old DB to new - - -
// # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

// - - -

// # # # # # # # # #
// - - - Users - - -
// # # # # # # # # # 

NSString *entityName = @"User";
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:oldManagedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSString *predicateFormat ;
NSPredicate *predicate;
error = nil;

NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResultsUsers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [oldManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]];

if (mutableFetchResultsUsers == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
NSLog(@"Users: %@", mutableFetchResultsUsers);
for(User *user in mutableFetchResultsUsers)
{
    NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@",user.userLogin,user.userDomain, user.serverAddress);
    User *userNew = [[DatabaseFactory sharedInstance] newObject:@"User"];
[...] // do here integration
    userNew.attibute = user.attribute;

    [self saveContext];
}
[request release];
request = nil;

// next one
```

hope I could help you a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using 2 persistent stores. One for the "readwrite" database, and one for the "readonly" (seed) database. In future versions of the application, I can ship updated seed database without any issues.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Define the Core Data version migration options
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                             nil];

    // Attempt to load the persistent store
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    // Create the default/ user model persistent store
    {
        NSString *storeFileName = ...;
        NSString *configuration = @"Readwite";
        NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationLocalDatabaseDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:storeFileName];

        if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                       configuration:configuration
                                                                 URL:storeURL
                                                             options:options
                                                               error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

    // Create the seed data persistent store
    {
        NSURL *seedDataURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SeedData" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
        NSString *configuration = @"SeedData";

        if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                       configuration:configuration
                                                                 URL:seedDataURL
                                                             options:options
                                                               error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]); abort();
            abort();
        }
    }

    // Developer's Note:
    // Instead of creating a single store, we created two persistent stores in an almost identical manner.
    // The only difference is that we explicitly named the configuration for the store to use, instead of
    // passing nil for the configuration parameter. Note that the configurations were set in xcdatamodeld file.

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Reference:

[Can multiple (two) persistent stores be used with one object model, while maintaining relations from one to the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231775/can-multiple-two-persistent-stores-be-used-with-one-object-model-while-mainta)