# CoreData: persistent and temporary storage

Tags: ios, core-data

I plan to use `CoreData` API for storing files in my `iOS` app. I want to have two stores of data: first, large, but possibly temporary, for caching; and second - small, but I want to ensure the data is persistent and never deleted. What are the best practices for doing this?

Comment: You want to store files, as in files of data? Or you want to store objects, in Core Data, in a database file?

Comment: @Wain I prefer using CoreData, but if there's an alternative solution which ensures persistency I'd use it

Comment: But what are you trying to store, what is the data?

Comment: @Wain only objects: some arrays of primitives and more complex objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create 2 separate Core Data 'stacks' - i.e. 2 different models (assuming the stored data is different in each), persistent stores, persistent store coordinators and managed object contexts. Both stacks will save the model to a file, but your temporary file should save into `NSTemporaryDirectory` (or perhaps better a cache directory) whereas your permanent file should be saved into `NSHomeDirectory`.

Other than that the usage of Core Data is nothing special. You just need to use the appropriate managed object context for the data you are saving / retrieving.

If you wanted to move any objects from one store to the other you would need to write the code to do that (i.e. get the object, create a new object in the other store and then copy each attribute across - use `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` and `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`).

Comment: This is correct, but using only one model and one moc can be more confortable ;-) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231775/can-multiple-two-persistent-stores-be-used-with-one-object-model-while-mainta)